# How to fix errors when running 'pip install python-binance'?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, binance

I ran the following command in cmd `pip install python-binance` and I got two Errors

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have absolutely NO IDEA how to fix this, I didn't find any solutions online, I'm new to programing so I really hope someone finds this and helps me, because otherwise, I'm stuck...
    **Thanks in advace.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the installer is unable to find a Visual Studio 14 installation, which has required Visual C++ build tools.  When working with a new package, you should read the documentation about installation and requirements.  It will help you resolve these kinds of issues.

From the docs:
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#installation

Windows

If you see errors building Twisted indication Microsoft Visual C++ is required you may need to install the Visual C++ Build Tools refer to the Python Wiki on Widows Compilers for your relevant version.

Comment: Thank you @HymnsForDisco, I really  didn't expect an answer this soon, I uninstalled all the Visuall C++ versions installed on my system, and reinstalled the latest versions, but now it's showing an new error `ERROR: Failed building wheel for twisted`, I tried updating Wheel, but it's already up to date

Comment: @Youyou. You could try searching stackoverflow for that new error message and see if any of the results help you.  If not, update your question with the full new error output

Comment: Thank you verry much, I've searched for a solution on StackOverflow, and I found one, I downloaded the Twisted package online, than I instaled it, after that I tried installing Python-Binance again, and it worked perfectly ! again, Thank you verry much